# How to access inventory_hostname from a filter_plugin?

Tags: ansible

My custom filter plugin uses `ansible.utils.display` to inject a warning in Ansible's output in some circumstances:

```python
    if 'hold' in mydetails:
        display.warning('%s can be upgraded from %s to %s, but is on hold' %
                        (myp, mydetails['version'], latest))
        continue
```

This works and the warning is displayed nicely, but lacks the hostname -- which could get rather confusing, when one's inventory is large. I could insert the hostname there myself, but I want to use exactly the string already known as `inventory_hostname`. How would I access that variable?

Comment: You can try to dig into [@environmentfilter](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/be3f911ce3fc1d46b11de394c1e76f3bf2f8f625/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py#L225) decorator. But I guess there's no context with hosts' variables for filters...

Comment: Not nice, but works - you could pass `inventory_hostname` as an optional filter parameter to your code.